# npm install -g bower on AWS Amazon ami getting error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bower, mean-stack

When I use the command: `npm install -g bower`

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/ec2-user/.npm/bower/1.3.12/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.14.20-20.44.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower" "-F"
npm ERR! node v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/var/www/html/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: A help window just pops up that tells me how to use npm.

Comment: Forgot to put install,  thanks it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either run the command using `sudo` or run the command normally as a user who has privileges to write to `/usr/local/lib`.

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Answer (score 2):

This line gives a lot of insight:

> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

As Anthony mentioned, try using `sudo npm install bower -g`.